# Shift/reduce conflict in java cup - dangling else issue

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, cup

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #116
between Statement ::= Matched (*) 
and     Unmatched ::= IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched (*) ELSE Unmatched 
and     Matched ::= IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched (*) ELSE Matched 
under symbol ELSE
Resolved in favor of shifting.
```

Now, i am aware of the dangling else problem, and i have tried making the grammar unambiguous:

```
Statement ::= Matched | Unmatched ;


Matched ::= IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ELSE Matched
            |
            Others
             ;

Unmatched ::= IF  LPAREN Condition RPAREN Statement 
              | 
              IF  LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ELSE Unmatched
              ;
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem without the precedence operator, or is there something else wrong with the grammar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar presented in the question, so my guess is that the shift/reduce conflict is the result of an interaction with another production.

The idea of splitting statements into `Matched` and `Unmatched`:

```
Statement ::= Matched | Unmatched ;
```

is precisely to ensure that an <kbd>else</kbd> is correctly matched with the nearest unmatched <kbd>if</kbd>. A `Matched` statement cannot be extended with an else clause; an `Unmatched` statement could have been. So we require that <kbd>else</kbd> tokens in the grammar cannot follow `Unmatched` statements, thus avoiding prematurely reducing a statement which might have been extended with an `else` clause.

So inside the `If` statement, the <kbd>else</kbd> can only follow a `Matched` statement. The statement itself is `Unmatched` if it doesn't have an `else` clause, or if the `else` clause itself is `Unmatched`. Thus, we have three productions:

```
Unmatched_If ::= IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Statement
               | IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ELSE Unmatched ;
Matched_If   ::= IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ELSE Matched ;
```

But this isn't the whole story, because there are other possible compound statements. Consider, for example, a `while` statement. If the language has such a construct, the grammar probably includes something like this:

```
While        ::= WHILE LPAREN Condition RPAREN Statement ; /* Wrong! */
```

That won't work, because a `while` statement can also be `Unmatched`, in precisely the same way that an `if...else` statement can be: if the interior `Statement` is `Unmatched`.

For example, consider

```
while (x) if (y) do_x_and_y;
```

With the incorrect `While` production above, that would be reduced as follows:

```
   WHILE LPAREN Condition RPAREN Unmatched_If
-> WHILE LPAREN Condition RPAREN Statement
-> Matched
```

But that violates the requirement that `Unmatched` cannot be followed by <kbd>else</kbd>. `Matched` can be followed by <kbd>else</kbd>, but in this case the `Matched` ends with `Unmatched_If`. And consequently, we have a shift/reduce conflict:

```
if (w)
  while (x) if (y) do_this;
else do_that;
```

This could be parsed as

```
IF ( Condition:[w] ) Matched:[while(x)if(y)do_this;] ELSE Statement:[do_that;]
```

But that is not actually the intended parse. (The indentation might lead us to think that it was the programmer's intent, but it is not the intent of the language designer.) The <kbd>else</kbd> should match the second <kbd>if</kbd>, not the first one, leading to:

```
if (w)
  while (x)
    if (y) do_this; else do_that;
```

So we need to distinguish between matched and unmatched `While` statements, not just matched and unmatched `If` statements:

```
Unmatched_While ::= WHILE LPAREN Condition RPAREN Unmatched ;
Matched_While   ::= WHILE LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ;
```

With that, `while (x) if (y) do_x_and_y;` will be parsed as an `Unmatched_While`, and so it can no longer be part of the productions which start `IF LPAREN Condition RPAREN Matched ELSE...`

Of course, the same will need to be done for other compound statements, such as `for` statements.

So the final result will be something like:

```
Matched   ::= Matched_If
            | Matched_While
            | Matched_For
            | ...
            | Simple_Statement
            ;
Unmatched ::= Unmatched_If
            | Unmatched_While
            | Unmatched_For
            | ...
            ;
```